# Fundamental polygon square $abab$

Tags: algebraic-topology, surfaces

What is the most convenient description of the space with fundamental polygon a square, with all vertices identified, glued by $abab$? If we were to identify only opposite vertices, we would get $\mathbb{R}P^2$. So I believe one description is $\mathbb{R}P^2$ with two points identified, which is homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb{R}P^2 \vee S^1$. Is this the best we can do, or is it something else in disguise?

[This](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/172784/do-all-combinatorially-distinct-fundamental-polygons-correspond-to-surfaces) answer suggests that it should be a surface, but I'm having a hard time seeing how it is. There is no neighborhood of the glued point homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$, is there? If so, how?

Comment: you could look at the euler characteristic, which is zero, so if it's actually a surface, then it would be either the klein bottle or torus. unless i'm mistaken, calculating the homology (using the cellular boundary maps) makes it clear that this isn't the case, so it's not a surface.

Comment: He identified all of the vertices here, though, so it should only have one vertex. Also I lied about the homology; it has the same homology as that of the klein bottle

Comment: @EricAuld It's just as you said : $\Bbb RP^2$ with two points identified, or in other words, $\Bbb RP^2 \vee S^1$. What more is there to be said? It's not a surface (look at the wedged point!) : I don't see where the MO answer suggests it is.

Comment: @BalarkaSen My reading was that the answer to the linked question said that each fundamental polygon corresponded to a surface. Or is there a general convention in fundamental polygons that tells you which vertices are identified? Perhaps the linked question took such a convention for granted?

Comment: @EricAuld The general convention for the fundamental polygon $abab$ is that you identify two opposite vertices, and not all of them, yes.

Comment: The general convention is that the side gluing induces a gluing relation on vertices: if a side with initial vertex $v_1$ and terminal vertex $w_1$ is identified to a side with initial vertex $v_2$ and terminal vertex $w_2$, then $v_1$ and $v_2$ are identified, also $w_1$ and $w_2$ are identified. This vertex gluing relation generates an equivalence relation on the vertex set of the polygon, whose different equivalence classes each determine different points of the quotient. With this convention, you always get a surface.

Comment: If you follow this convention with the $abab$ gluing, then as in the comment of @BalarkaSen, each diagonally opposite pair of vertices forms an equilance class, and in the quotient there are two different points.

Answer (score 1):

I'm putting what I have wrote in the comments together in this answer :

**Claim** The polygon $abab$ with all the vertices identified is homotopy equivalent $\Bbb RP^2 \vee S^1$.

First consider the polygon $abab$ with diagonally opposite pair of vertices identified, which is homeomorphic to $\Bbb RP^2$. Since all of the vertices must be identified, attach a $1$-cell to the resulting space along the disjoint union of the unidentified vertices; nullhomotoping the attaching map along the surface of $\Bbb RP^2$ gives you the desired homotopy type.

You can see that this is not a surface by looking at the wedged point. Any neighborhood of the wedge point looks like an open disk wedge $(0, 1)$, which is certainly not homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^2$.

As for the polygon in the MO question, the standard convention for identification on the polygon of $abab$ is that you identify diagonally opposite pairs of vertices, so that's just the usual $\Bbb RP^2$.